# What to do for the right FFT in Matlab (two peaks and incorrect amplitude)?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, acoustics

This is the FFT I'm using. But two peaks (did not expect the one in the beginning) are occurring and the amplitude is not as specified (expecting a value of 2). Any help is much appreciated!

```
Amp = 2;
freqHz = 10000;
fsHz = freqHz*2+1;
dt = 1/fsHz;

sine = Amp*sin(2*pi*freqHz*(0:dt:1-dt));

transform = fft(sine,fsHz)/fsHz;
magTransform = abs(transform);

faxis = linspace(0,fsHz/2,fsHz);
plot(faxis,fftshift(magTransform));
xlabel('Frequency')
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is: how many peaks did you expect (and why) vs how many you're getting; and what amplitude did you expect (and why) vs what you're actually getting. Do not add this information as a comment; rather, edit your question.

Comment: Please see the picture I've uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use complex signal for that. Use this

`Amp = 2;
freqHz = 10000; 
fsHz = freqHz*2+1; 
dt = 1/fsHz; 
sine = Amp*exp(2i*pi*freqHz*(0:dt:1-dt));
 transform = fft(sine,fsHz)/fsHz; magTransform = abs(transform); 
faxis = linspace(-fsHz/2,fsHz/2,fsHz); plot(faxis,fftshift(magTransform)); xlabel('Frequency')`

Answer (score 0):

The somehow symeetric aspect of the complex DFT might be misleading, so in the past I shared a simple Matlab function [FFTR.m](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/Documents-Common/FFTR.m) for real signals only, that might yield the result you'd expect ($2$ magnitude at peak frequency):

[image: FFRT: FFT for real signals]

as long as you don't try bordeline endeavours. That requires a little normalization and a special care at DC and Nyquist. The code could be:

```
% Signal definition
Amp = 2;
freqHz = 10000;
fsHz = freqHz*2+1;
dt = 1/fsHz;
sine = Amp*sin(2*pi*freqHz*(0:dt:1-dt));

% Graphic part
[fftR,fftAxe] = FFTR(sine',dt);
plot(fftAxe,fftR,'o-');
xlabel('Frequency')
ylabel('Magnitude')
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I achieve this with the built in function?

Comment: Just explore the FFT.m link I gave as a link, and steal the code :)

Comment: And if you like it, don't hesitate to upvote!

Comment: Unfortunately my rep is not sufficient :/